# Multiple instances of .NET console app that opens winform throws intermittent access violation

Tags: vb.net, winforms, console-application, access-violation

We have a .NET console application that launches a winform (winform is in a .NET dll that is merged into the console exe).  It is used as a print router, and launched from a web page.

The main method looks like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim pf As PrintForm = New PrintForm()
        pf.ShowDialog()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error has occured. Please contact your System Administrator.")
    End Try
End Sub
```

We find when multiple instances of the console application are open, (some clients operate in a Citrix environment, where multiple users are logged into the same OS, and even in a normal environment is is not uncommon for users to have several browser tabs open and be printing from multiple tabs which in turn launches multiple instances of the exe), that we intermittently encounter the following error:

> Exception Message: Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as
>   a modal dialog box. Set the form's visible property to false before
>   calling showDialog.

I can't see why this would be happening, as each instance of the console exe (which is started by a java applet using Runtime.exec), should start in its own instance.

In an effort to get around the above issue I tried changing the code to the following:

```
<STAThread>
Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim pf As PrintForm = New PrintForm()
        Application.Run(pf)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error has occured. Please contact your System Administrator.")
    End Try
End Sub
```

We no longer intermittently get the above error, instead we now intermittently get the following error:

> Exception Message: Starting a second message loop on a single thread
>   is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead.

So it seems I can't win.

Has anyone out there had a similar issue, and if so how did you resolve it?
Or can anyone offer some direction/advise on how to go about solving this one?

This is legacy code, and so I did not design it to use a console application, this is the solution that is already in place.  A windows form is something I could try, but I wanted to see if there was a solution that didn't involve rewriting the application.  There is a bit more going on than the simple example I gave above to convey the concept of what we are doing.

Thanks for your time.

UPDATE# 1:

Ok so I created a VB.NET WinForms application and moved the copied the forms from the console exe into the WinForms application.

It still has the same problem, except I get less debug info now.  I can replicate the issue with a single instance of the application running, but now when the debugger breaks, (I can replicate it when running the exe manually, and when running with VS debugger), I get no disassembly available, and line of source.
The error message is:

> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

And the call stack is:

```
Application: PrintForm.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip+ToolTipNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(System.String[])
   at PrintForm.My.MyApplication.Main(System.String[])
```

When I get this error I am alt+tab focus from a PDF viewer that's program window is overlapping the application window, back to the WinForms Application.
It doesn't happen if the PDF viewers window is not overlapping the WinForms Application window.

It is worth mentioning that the icon in the WinForms application that launches the PDF viewer (using the shell) has a tool tip.

Again it is intermittent.  But it happens often enough to be a problem.

UPDATE# 2:

I have now replicated it, without even launching the PDF, but just alt+tabing from Windows Explorer back to the Winforms Application and back again... where the Windows Explorer window overlaps the Winforms Application.  So all the Winforms Application has done in this scenario is start and become visible.

Comment: What happens when you change the application to be a Windows Application, instead of a Console? Console applications are not meant to launch forms. Your application is so small I would personally just create a brand new Windows Forms application and launch my form from that.

Comment: `Console applications are not meant to launch forms.` according to whom? While they may not have the references automatically imported, they still have the ability to launch forms and manipulate them as *any other project would*.

Comment: If all you want is an application that shows a form then you want a Windows Application. Otherwise you are just fighting against the grain; you need to set the thread apartment, start the message loop, hide the console... If strange things were happening for me in this situation I would go back to basics and try a different approach: i.e. a Windows Application.

Comment: Can you explain why you chose to have a Console application that displays a form and then closes rather than just having a Windows Forms application that would do the same thing? As suggested, the solution seems rather obvious, unless there is some specific reason that you need a Console application that apparently doesn't do what a Console application normally does but does do what a Windows Forms application normally does.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I have updated the question with detail on why a console application is used.

Comment: You may be investigating the wrong code.  Look at the code of `PrintForm`.  There could be something (an event triggered) in that code that is showing the form after is constructed, but before the console app is showing it.

Comment: @AlexM. : The issue is there are more things than library references that come into play when creating windows applications. Having a proper message loop being one of them.

Comment: @AlexM. : Just because something works that doesn't mean it's recommended or even good practice to do so. :)

Comment: OP: Are you sure the application is started as a separate process? Perhaps it's still run under the Java VM (process?) seeing as the second error says that there already is a message loop on _**the current thread**_.

Comment: @VisualVincent when you press the print button on the webpage, it opens a popup window that loads the java applet.  The java applet downloads (if not already there) the console exe and then launches it, and then closes the popup window.  So the java applet is no longer running at this time.  I have view the java console to confirm that the applet closes after launching the console exe.

Comment: Just out curiosity, have you verified that it is a re-entry into `Sub Main` issue by setting a counter  with a conditional check?  Also, did you try the solution offered by the error message `"Set the form's visible property to false before calling showDialog"`?

Comment: @TnTinMn The counter is idea is great I will give that a go.  ShowDialog was the original method used, but gave me the first error message in the ticket "Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Set the form's visible property to false before calling showDialog.".  So I changed to Show to solve that problem, and then got the second error message saying use ShowDialog.

Comment: You will need to use ShowDialog so that the form runs in a modal message loop context.  Or you can use `Application.Run(form)` as you showed in your alternate method to start the form in a message loop.  If you look at the source code for the [ShowDialog Method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,ab288b84e00f8282,references) you can see where the exception originates from if the form is already visible.

Comment: @TnTinMn Yes but I don't understand why it would say the form is already visible, as each time the console exe is started from the command line by the java app, it should be running a separate instance, and so ShowDialog should only ever be called once in each instance... This is where your counter idea could be used... but even if it shows there is a second call... we still have no solution....  I think we are going to rewrite the console exe as a Windows Form application instead, and see this resolves our issues.

Comment: Did you follow my earlier advice concerning a review of the PrintForm code to see if there is a chance that any code in that class could be setting Visible=True (or a Me.Show call)? In any case, I wish you good luck solving the issue.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks for following up.  I did a search of the entire project for ".Show" and ".Visible" and there is nothing related to the PrintForm other than the one call in the console exe.

Comment: Hmm, strange... The application must run under some kind of sandbox since it always seems to run on the same thread.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes tis a strange one for sure... especially since it doesn't happen when the application opens... it happens while you are using it... and not when you doing anything that opens a window.... sometimes just when the program window is open and you not doing anything...